# Sending HTML Mail with image, add attachment "noname"

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i'm trying to send an email, using javax.mail.

The trouble is that , i have 2 images in the html code and those images appears properly in the mail body.

But i have also 2 files ("noname") attach with this email .

Here's the code :

```
   BodyPart messageBodyPart ; 
   // Add HTML + image       
   // first part (the html)
   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
   //multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");   
   messageBodyPart.setContent(Constantes.html  + msg +"</h4>", "text/html");
   // add it
   messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
   //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

   // second part ( image 1)
   BodyPart messageBodyPartSMSC = new MimeBodyPart();
   DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Constantes.imagePath + "logo1.png");

   messageBodyPartSMSC.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
   messageBodyPartSMSC.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo1>");       
   // add image to the multipart
   messageBodyPartSMSC.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
  // multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // second part ( image 2)
   BodyPart messageBodyPartDEVB = new MimeBodyPart();
   fds = new FileDataSource(Constantes.imagePath + "logo2.png");

   messageBodyPartDEVB.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
   messageBodyPartDEVB.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo2>");
   messageBodyPartDEVB.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
   // add image to the multipart
   //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


    // add attachment (zip file) ------------------------------

   DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
   BodyPart messageBodyPartZip = new MimeBodyPart();
   messageBodyPartZip.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
   messageBodyPartZip.setFileName(onlyFileName);
   messageBodyPartZip.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);

   MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");



    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartSMSC);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartDEVB);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartZip);


   // Send the complete message parts
   message.setContent(multipart);


   Transport.send(message);
```

May anyone have an answer ?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The multipart/related should be nested in a multipart/mixed, which also contains the attachments:

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart ;
// Add HTML + image      
// first part (the html)
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeMultipart related = new MimeMultipart("related");  
messageBodyPart.setContent(Constantes.html  + msg +"</h4>", "text/html");
// add it
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
related.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// second part ( image 1)
BodyPart messageBodyPartSMSC = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Constantes.imagePath + "logo1.png");

messageBodyPartSMSC.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPartSMSC.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo1>");      
// add image to the multipart
messageBodyPartSMSC.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
related.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 // second part ( image 2)
BodyPart messageBodyPartDEVB = new MimeBodyPart();
fds = new FileDataSource(Constantes.imagePath + "logo2.png");

messageBodyPartDEVB.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPartDEVB.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo2>");
messageBodyPartDEVB.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
// add image to the multipart
related.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 
MimeBodyPart rbp = new MimeBodyPart(); 
rbp.setContent(related); 
multipart.addBodyPart(rbp); 

 // add attachment (zip file) ------------------------

BodyPart messageBodyPartZip = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
messageBodyPartZip.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPartZip.setFileName(onlyFileName);
messageBodyPartZip.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
// or replace the above 4 lines with:
// messageBodyPartZIP.attachFile(fileName);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartZip);

// Send the complete message parts
message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

You can also simplify the structure by including the images in the html as inline data.  In that case you wouldn't need the multipart/related at all and can add the html body part as the first body part in the multipart/mixed.
See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer .i will follow your link soon or later .

Comment: I cannot pass after the line `multipart.addBodypart(rbp);`. The error is `SendEmail.java: : error: cannot find symbol multipart.addBodypart(rbp);`, `variable multipart of type MimeMultipart`

Comment: Besides, this do not solve the problem. The "noname" attachment are still in there. Unless there are other change not exposed in the shown code.

Comment: Ultimately you're at the mercy of your mail reader as to how it displays the message.  Some mail readers will understand that the parts are not attachments, many won't.  Include the images in the html as inline data.